# AngularJS: migrating from $scope with components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to replace some functionality in an app that I got working with `$scope` and `$scope.$parent`, where based on behaviour that happens within a child component I can call a method stored in a parent component, on values in the parent.

```
function ChildController($scope) {
    $scope.doThing = function() {
        $scope.$parent.doThing()
    }

function ParentController($scope) {
    ...
    $scope.stuff = {...};
    $scope.doThing = function() {
        // does thing to stuff
    }
}
```

These days, I'm using `var ctrl = this;` more and I'm wondering how I *should* handle this. I've experimented with component bindings but it seemed like they were a bit off the mark. Anyone know how best to go about this?

I'm using angularjs 1.6.1 and I'm working on an internal system, so importing other scripts isn't really an option. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can pass the function from parent to child using component bindings

Comment: When I tried this it seemed like it was creating a local version of the function and therefore not affecting the parent data. Is this the intended behaviour or was that a problem on my end?

Comment: Can you show how you tried it?

Comment: That's probably worth a whole other question, if that's just a bug. I'll look into bindings some more to see if it's possible to go that route, it did seem like it would make a lot of sense that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example turning both into components, you can leave the parent a controller if you wish.  The thing most people find strange is having to send in an object for the parameters when using the '&' function binding.  If you don't need to return parameters then that makes it easier :)  Hope this helps.

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>simple component example</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <parent-component></parent-component>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myApp', [])

    .component('parentComponent', {
      controller: function() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.handleClick = function(id) { console.log(id) };
      },
      template: '<child-component click-me="$ctrl.handleClick(id)" greeting="hello"></child-component>'
    })

    .component('childComponent', {
      bindings: { greeting: '@', clickMe: '&' },
      template:`
        <div>
          <h1>{{$ctrl.greeting}}</h1>
          <button ng-click="$ctrl.clickMe({id: '101010'})">Run Parent Function</button>
        </div>
      `,
      controller: function() {
        var ctrl = this;
        console.log(this);
      }
    });

})();
```

Plunker [Here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/wgobkYuRFY0pOezZ)

**Updated Code to modify something in parent.**  Notice that I changed the greeting binding from a '@' (string literal) to a '<' (one way binding expression).  Now the id sent back to the parent function will be appended to the greeting variable in the parent function, which is sent to the child for display.  **I have updated the plunker as well**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myApp', [])

    .component('parentComponent', {
      controller: function() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.greeting = 'hello';
        ctrl.handleClick = function(id) { ctrl.greeting += id };
      },
      template: '<child-component click-me="$ctrl.handleClick(id)" greeting="$ctrl.greeting"></child-component>'
    })

    .component('childComponent', {
      bindings: { greeting: '<', clickMe: '&' },
      template:`
        <div>
          <h1>{{$ctrl.greeting}}</h1>
          <button ng-click="$ctrl.clickMe({id: '101010'})">Run Parent Function</button>
        </div>
      `
    });

})();
```

Comment: Would this still work if `handleClick` did something to an object in the parent controller? This looks promising but that's the issue I was having when I tried bindings.

Comment: @Paw please see above updated code.  I believe this is what you're looking for?  Plunker updated as well

Comment: Update: turns out the bug was caused by the parent being a controller! Not really sure why but without the parent methods being passed on by a bonafide component it did some very odd sort of half-binding. Encasing the parent controller in a component solved the problem.